# Cannot connect to the Jenkins slave machine when running Jenkins as a java prgoram

Tags: jenkins, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

When I set up my Jenkins master using the windows installer version and attempt to connect to a slave machine using "Launch Jenkins via Java webstart", I can connect the slave server to the master fine with no issues.

[image]

However, I'm now required to launch the jenkins Master using "java -jar jenkins.war" so I can see the GUI interface being tested in realtime, but I cannot seem to create a connection to the slave machine this way (when I try to access the url on the slave machine, it says it cannot be displayed).

[image]

Is it possible to connect with jenkins while it is being run as a java program? Or is there an alternative method I can use?

EDIT: Below is a copy of the console output when I start jenkins on the console.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins.war
Running from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:09 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Logging initialized @279ms
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:09 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
←[33mOct 11, 2016 3:07:09 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: Empty contextPath
←[0mOct 11, 2016 3:07:09 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:10 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
Jenkins home directory: C:\Users\user\.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:11 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started w.@1aac487{/,file:/C:/Users/user/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Us
ers\user\.jenkins\war}
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:11 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started ServerConnector@1154ccd{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:11 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started @1571ms
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:11 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:11 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:11 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:14 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:15 PM hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1
error
INFO: Failed to instantiate optional component hudson.plugins.build_timeout.oper
ations.AbortAndRestartOperation$DescriptorImpl; skipping
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:16 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:16 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:16 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:16 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Download metadata
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:16 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 4 ms
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:17 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationC
ontext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationCon
text@150b22a: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Tue Oct 1
1 15:07:17 BST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:17 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationC
ontext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.supp
ort.StaticWebApplicationContext@150b22a]: org.springframework.beans.factory.supp
ort.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b4a611
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:17 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListabl
eBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b4a611: defining beans [authenticationManager]; root
 of factory hierarchy
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:17 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationC
ontext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationCon
text@10920bb: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Tue Oct 1
1 15:07:17 BST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:17 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationC
ontext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.supp
ort.StaticWebApplicationContext@10920bb]: org.springframework.beans.factory.supp
ort.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1403952
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:17 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListabl
eBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
DefaultListableBeanFactory@1403952: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of fact
ory hierarchy
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:17 PM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD start
INFO: Started SSHD at port 56276
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:17 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Oct 11, 2016 3:07:17 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

Comment: Do you see any error messages when you launch Jenkins from the command line ?  The log output should go to the console unless you redirect it.

Comment: On the master? There is one or two warnings and errors but I'm not sure if they are connected. I've edited my post to include the console output if you'd like to see for yourself. Could "WARNING: Empty contextPath" be related?

Comment: @LeChuck Did you get a solution for this issue?